# Outlook 2019 wrong date locale in replies

Tags: microsoft-outlook, locale, microsoft-outlook-2019

When I reply to an email message in Outlook 2019, the original mails date is written in US format, instead of the system locale (the original mail has it in correct format, see screenshot).

I found [here on MS answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/office-365-outlook-v1809-date-format-in-reply-is/f321c9b3-0661-47c7-9212-7416b47ee0f5) a similar report, but no solution.

[image]

The date in other places in Outlook and also in systray (second screenshot below) and other programs is in correct format. Just in replies it gets converted to US format.

This happens also to messages I send to myself (as test), so it is not some weird setting on the senders side.

My OS is Windows 10 Pro version 1909, the mail server is Exchange.

[image]

Comment: According to my research and test, I'm afraid this is by design and you may not be able to change it. It is suggested to share your feedback via the Outlook UserVoice forum:https://outlook.uservoice.com/forums/322590-outlook-2016-for-windows(For all versions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to turn off this option (File/Options):

[image]